# CanCan - Specifying that a role can modify a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

This is how my database should be laid out.

```
User (one) => many Computers (one) => many Accounts
```

I am trying to set up [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) so that only the owner of the computer can edit an account. This is what I have so far.

```
user ||= User.new 
if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
else
    can :manage, Computer, :user_id => user.id # <= works
    can :manage, Account, :computer => {:user_id => user.id} # <= doesnt work
end
```

The second can does not work. I would like it so that I can have a user be able to edit all the accounts associated with all of his computers. Any ideas to why this isn't working?
I have tried implementing some of the ways that the [guide](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) says to but those aren't working either.

Comment: make sure that `user.id` is not `nil` which is the case when user is a new record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation and was able to make it work with:

```
can :manage, Account, computer_id: user.computers.collect(&:id)
```

So, basically, the user can manage accounts that have computer_ids associated to the user.

Comment: you should use `user.computer_ids` instead of collect so no active_record objects are created